How to run shell command for list with two strings
I would like to run a shell command with ansible that it formatted in this way:
command <item_1> <item_2>

and to loop for multiple items such as:

<item_1_v1> <item_2_v1>
<item_1_v2> <item_2_v2>

What would be the best way to achieve it?
Sincerely

A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - command:
      cmd: 'echo "cmd {{ item.p_1 }} {{ item.p_2 }}"'
    register: result
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.p_1 }} {{ item.p_2 }}"
    loop:
      - { p_1: 1_v1, p_2: 2_v1 }
      - { p_1: 1_v2, p_2: 2_v2 }
      - { p_1: 1_v3, p_2: 2_v3 }

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    loop: "{{ result.results }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [command] ***************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=1_v1 2_v1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=1_v2 2_v2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=1_v3 2_v3)

TASK [debug] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=cmd 1_v1 2_v1) =>
  msg: cmd 1_v1 2_v1
ok: [localhost] => (item=cmd 1_v2 2_v2) =>
  msg: cmd 1_v2 2_v2
ok: [localhost] => (item=cmd 1_v3 2_v3) =>
  msg: cmd 1_v3 2_v3


You can run a command using the ansible.builtin.command module.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html
Example:
- name: Run command if /path/to/database does not exist (with 'args' keyword)
  ansible.builtin.command: /usr/bin/make_database.sh db_user db_name

OR
- name: Run command using argv with mixed argument formats
  ansible.builtin.command:
    argv:
      - /path/to/binary
      - -v
      - --debug
      - --longopt
      - value for longopt
      - --other-longopt=value for other longopt
      - positional

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#examples
If you would like to run multiple commands, you can do as suggested here and do the following:
- command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
  - ./configure
  - /usr/bin/make
  - /usr/bin/make install


And what about looping instructions?

I edited my answer.
